# java local variable synchronization

Tags: java, multithreading

I have problem with following java code, this program always give "KKBB" as the output (so it seems like synchronization works ), So i am unable to understand since i is a local variable why synchronization is working here?

```
class Test implements Runnable {
    public void run() {
        Integer i=10;
        synchronized(i)
        {
            try {
                System.out.print(Thread.currentThread().getName());
                Thread.sleep(1200);
                System.out.print(Thread.currentThread().getName());
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            }
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new Thread(new Test(), "K").start();
        new Thread(new Test(), "B").start();
    }
}
```

I heard that since local variables have different copies for each methods, so synchronization won't work, please help me  to understand, thanks

Comment: Re, "since i is a local variable..."  The `synchronized(i)` statement does not operate on the _variable_, it operates on the _object_ to which the variable refers.  As @chrylis pointed out, `Integer.valueOf(10)` always refers to the same cached Integer object.

Answer (score 8):

The wrapper classes have special behavior for small values. If you use `Integer.valueOf()` (or `Short`, `Char`, or `Byte`) for a value between -128 and 127, you'll get a shared cached instance.

The autoboxing treats

```
Integer i = 10;
```

as

```
Integer i = Integer.valueOf(10);
```

so the different `i` variables are actually referring to the same instance of `Integer` and thus share a monitor.

Comment: Right -- you don't synchronize on the variable, you synchronize on the object.